# How do i get the value of first index in a returned List of array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am using C# windows form

I have a List of arrays from a function in a class and I called the function into the form
the function returned a List of arrays, how do i get the value of the arrays?

Here is my List of array code

```
    public List<string[]> getAccounts()
    {
        List<string[]> account = new List<string[]>();

        while (*condition*)
        {
            string[] users = new string[2];
            users[0] = user["firstname"].ToString();
            users[1] = user["lastname"].ToString();
            account.Add(users);
        }
        return account;
    }
```

and when i call the function I want to show all the firstname into a listbox as well as the last name into another listbox

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= acc.getAccounts().Count; i++)
        {
            listBoxFirstname.Items.Add(*all the first name from the list*);
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a lambda expression to iterate through the list and select the first name

```
account.ForEach(s => listBoxFirstname.Items.Add(s[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a lambda expression:

```
List<string[]> accounts = acc.getAccounts()
for (int i = 1; i < accounts ; i++)
{
    listBoxFirstname.Items.Add(account[i][0]);
    listBoxLastname.Items.Add(account[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think will be better to use SelectMany.

```
listBoxFirstname.Items.AddRange(acc.getAccounts().SelectMany(item=>item[0]))
```

[AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Sorry, i'm blind, you can do it without Select many - you can just use Select

```
listBoxFirstname.Items.AddRange(acc.getAccounts().Select(item=>item[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
List<string> firstNames = account.Select(item => item[0]).ToList();
```